# Change mousepointer during drag

Tags: python, pyqt4, mouse-cursor

How can I change the mousepointer/cursor during drag in PyQt4 (I want one mouse pointer in the left side of my widget and another pointer in the right part):

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Button(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        self.drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        self.drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        self.drag.start(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.button = Button("Drag me", self)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        pm = QtGui.QPixmap(32,32)

        if e.pos().x()<150:
            pm.fill(QtCore.Qt.blue)    
            self.button.drag.setDragCursor(pm,QtCore.Qt.CopyAction) #Not working
        else:
            pm.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)    
            self.button.drag.setDragCursor(pm,QtCore.Qt.MoveAction) #Not working

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
ex = Example()
ex.show()
app.exec_()
```

This code however, does not change the mouse cursor.

Thanks in advance
Mads

Comment: I assume you're not talking about `QDrag.setDragCursor`. Can you give an example of what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Cde snippet added.    QDrag.setDragCursor    do not work for me either

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of what you are doing?